# The maximum principle for subharmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, potential-theory

Let $V$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $n\geq2$, and $u$ a subharmonic function on an open set containing the closure $ \overline{V} $ of $V$. Suppose 
we have $u<M$ on $V$ ($M$ is a constant). Can we conclude that $u\leq M$ on $ \overline{V} $?

Comment: Do you allow your subharmonic functions to attain the value $-\infty$?

Comment: Yes, but cannot be identically $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a partial answer to this question: if $u$ is continuous at each point of the boundary $\partial V$ of $V$, the answer is yes! In fact, we have by continuity of $u$ and the maximum principle, 
$$u(\zeta)=\limsup_{\substack{x\rightarrow\zeta\\(x\in V)}}u(x)\leq M$$
for all point $\zeta\in\partial V$, which proves the claim!

Comment: This actually works for all functions that are continuous on the boundary, as $u(x)<M$ for all $x\in V$ by assumption. No need for the maximum principle.